# How to filter <str> and filter it by index 1,2,3.. in python

Tags: python, string

I have three variable that store str value.
Example:

```
dataTOcompare[dataTOcompare_index][0] = 'header1 : Subject', 'header2 :Text'

dataTOcompare[dataTOcompare_index][1] = 'condition1 : Equal', 'condition2: Contain '

dataTOcompare[dataTOcompare_index][2] = 'parameter1: hi1', 'parameter2: hi2'
```

**What i trying to achieved:**

I want it to pair each index 1,2,3 with three different str. For example, `header1,condition1, parameter1` should be one data eg.

Expected output:

```
header1, condition1, parameter1 = Subject Equal hi1
```

```
header2, condition2, parameter2 = Text Contain hi2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to split the string containing key-value pairs at `:`, then get the second value, which is the value of your key-value pair, strip the white spaces and then add them to the tuple. Using [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) you can iterate over multiple iterables at the same time.

```py
input_header = 'header1 : Subject', 'header2 :Text'
input_conditions = 'condition1 : Equal', 'condition2: Contain '
input_parameters = 'parameter1: hi1', 'parameter2: hi2'


def getValue(string):
    return string.split(":")[1].strip()


result = [(getValue(header), getValue(condition), getValue(parameter)) for header, condition, parameter in
          zip(input_header, input_conditions, input_parameters)]
print(result)
```

Expected output:

```
[('Subject', 'Equal', 'hi1'), ('Text', 'Contain', 'hi2')]
```

You inputs though seem to be very quite odd. So if you can control it, just use simple arrays. Your key-value pairs as a string are not necessary as the key does not represent something meaningful and even if it was it is just a string not a dictionary that you can access easily using that key. You could use an array instead to achieve the same thing you are trying to do.

```py
headers = ["Subject", "Text"]
conditions = ["Equal", "Contain"]
parameters = ["hi1", "hi2"]
result = list(zip(headers, conditions, parameters))

print(result)
```

This will produce the same output as what you have done above.

Comment: Hi thanks for ur respond, it worked well. But how can i access element inside the specific list? For example, `[('Subject', 'Equal', 'hi1'), ('Text', 'Contain', 'hi2')]` How can I take only the first list `Subject` ?

Comment: Use `result[0][0]` to get the subject of the first tuple. Use `result[0][1]` to get the condition. and use `result[1][0]` to get the subject of the second tuple.

Comment: What if the tuple item is generated dynamically? Its not practical if i hard code the [0][0] because there will have new data input by user

Comment: No need to hard code. It is a list so you can iterate over it and each tuple will always contain 3 values which are `(header, condition, parameter)` so you could loop over however many results you have using `for header, condition, parameter in result:
    print(header, condition, parameter)`